# Handling a POST AJAX request on an SSL server from a non-SSL server

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, ssl

Is there any way to POST an AJAX form from an HTTP server to an HTTPS server?

I have a WordPress JSON API service running on SSL, and when I POST to it from a non-secure server, the API method does run, but the $_POST variables are all empty.

I don't see any errors either.

Comment: you mean, from a web browser on an http site to a server over https? yeah, that's possible. you just gotta follow CORS rules.

Comment: @KevinB Hmm well I'm using JSONP, isn't that enough? My GET requests work. Am I wrong to assume that this is an SSL issue?

Comment: JSONP can't be a POST request. JSONP requests are made be injecting a script tag into the page, and script tags can't send post requests.

Comment: @KevinB but that's how I got round the `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` error. Is that wrong?

Comment: That workaround only works for GET.

Comment: @KevinB ok so I have to specify the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on the server side?

Comment: yes, that's part of what CORS requires.